# how to insert data manual in sqlite database?

Tags: android

I would like to insert data manual in sqlite database.
using cmd to insert data.
I used data in android project.

Comment: You mean from the development machine into a database on a device?

Comment: Do you have database in your data/data/yourpackage ?

Comment: yes i hava a database in data/data/mypackage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Follow the Below Step .

In Command Prompt .

```
1) Go to your sdk-tool directory . (Example - E:\android-sdk-windows\tools>)
2) Type adb shell and press enter
3) # cd data
4) # cd data
5) #cd your package name
6) #cd databases
7) #sqlite3 your_database_name.db
```

It will open a sqlite3 prompt where you can  manually create a tables and insert data into them .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data manually from your development machine, then you should first download **SQLite manager** from here: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/ , and then insert all the data which you want inside database.

Once you are done with inserting, then import that database into the data folder of your application.