# How insert data manually in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to  retrieve data from sqlite and put it into a spinner[like having provinces and cities so i want a selected province to populate its Cities] so i manage to do DBAdapter..

1) I want to put province and cities into a database, i tried but my last option is to put it manually..so can anyone help me..HOW TO INSERT DATA MANUAL INTO DATABASE and I dont have a database yet.

So here what I have tried since in the morning...

```
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ProvinceTable + " ("+ COLUMN_PID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT , " + COLUMN_PName + "TEXT)" );

     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Cities_TABLE + " ("+COLUMN_CID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +COLUMN_CityNames+" TEXT," +
            ""+ COLUMN_Lat +" INTEGER, "+COLUMN_Long + " INTEGER , " + COLUMN_PID + " INTEGER NOT NULL , FOREIGN KEY ("+ COLUMN_PID +") REFERENCES " + ProvinceTable + "("+COLUMN_PID + "));");
```

I've tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307769/how-to-insert-data-manual-in-sqlite-database) solution but i'm lost I dont understand the steps

Answer (score 2):

Creating a database is actually quite simple on your development computer.  Use `sqlite3` tool:

```
$ sqlite3 my_database;
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE province_table (pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pname TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO province_table (pname) values ('Quebec');
sqlite> ...
sqlite> .q
```

Enter `.q` to quit when you're done.  Now your have file called `my_database` containing your database with all the tables and data that you created.  Feel free to rename it if you want to.  Now all you need to do is to add it to your app project.

If you don't have this tool, you can download it at the [sqlite website](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: Tanx, but please provide me with steps to go to sqlite tool and what to click

Comment: sqlite tool is a command-line tool.  Go to the web site, download the tool for your platform (windows/mac/linux/etc), follow the instructions to install it.  Once installed, open command prompt (on windows) or terminal window (on mac os x or linux/unix) and type in exactly what I put in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this it will help you..

```
public class AutoHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

public AutoHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context,"County.db",null,1);  
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE County(auto INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,path TEXT);");   
    Log.v("AUTOHELP:","TABLE CREATED");
}

public void insert(String path)
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("path",path);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("County",null,cv);
    Log.e("ORG HELPER :","VALUES INSERTED");
}

public Cursor getPath()
{
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT path FROM County",null)); 
}

public String getAutoname(Cursor c)
{
    return(c.getString(0)); 
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
}
}
```